# Is my Optoma HD20 projector repairable?

Tags: repair, home-theater, projector

I've just come home from a trip and found that my Optoma HD20 appears to be broken. 
When I turned it on, I don't get the usual Optoma logo, but instead unmoving static broken by a black bar. 
[image]

Prepared to replace - it's served me well since 2012 - but interested in what might have broken, and whether it can be repaired?

I had the 'vertical lines' issue a couple of years ago, which went away when I pushed on top of the bulb, I don't know if that's relevant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I tore it down to below the main board and gave the Dmd/main board socket a good clean with some Servisol and reseated (if someone else comes across this, here's a good video guide - https://youtu.be/8iLR2viox8U) and it's back to its usual self. And I only damaged one ribbon connector holder and left one spare spacer on reassembly. £500 saved for now.